# How to access Minecraft screenshot saved to a root folder?

Tags: permissions, nautilus, root

I play minecraft. When I take a screenshot in game it saves to a root folder. To see the screenshot I need to enter a password every time.

How can access that folder any time without entering a password? I tried `gksu nautilus`, `sudo nautilus`, and `sudo -i nautilus`. The Files app crashed every time.

Comment: " it saves to a root folder" what folder? and why? minecraft installed as a user would use a dir inside your home owned by your user.  Please do not use sudo with a filemanager; it will mess up permissions.

Comment: It is recommended by the installer to install it with sudo, and thats how it gets installed in /root/.minecraft

Comment: by who?  "sudo" does NOT use /root/. Only the root user uses /root as that is the home for  user root. The home for the admin user is /home/$USER/.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Let's start with the fact that this appears to be a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/902710).  You asked about how to access the screenshots in the `/root` folder, but your *actual problem* is that Minecraft is saving screenshots to that folder in the first place.

First, as @Rinzwind mentioned in the comments, it's just not recommended to use a file manager as `sudo`.  Use the command-line to `cp` and `chown` of the files in this case.

Second, as mentioned in the comments, Minecraft simply shouldn't be *able* to save files in the `/root` directory, and the fact that it can do so is a ***major concern***.

Installing the `Minecraft.deb` (or any similar package) using `sudo dpkg -t` is *expected* and normal.  However, if Minecraft is *running* as root, then that's an issue.  In no case should an application which is launched by a user have access to the `/root` directory unless it also is run through `sudo` or the executable is set SUID.  Neither of those should be the case.

I just installed and ran Minecraft on Ubuntu (*under* WSL, which is odd, but a valid test-case) and screenshots were created in my *user* home directory, under `$HOME/.minecraft/screenshots`.  The fact that yours is not is a security issue.

Recommendations:

- As @Rinzwind correctly points out in a comment on this answer, just the fact that you have run Minecraft as root (regardless of how that happens) has opened your *entire* system to a chance of exploit.  As a popular game, Minecraft is, unfortunately, often a target for hackers.  I agree that it is *not* unreasonable to suggest a full reinstall of the system at this point regardless of the cause.

  Since a keylogger could have been installed, consider changing any passwords that you may have used on this system, including (but not limited to) the Minecraft username and password.  It's *especially* important to change your e-mail password if you believe your system may have been compromised, as hackers will take that over *first* in order to use your e-mail to change the passwords on other accounts.
- Next, obviously, is to make sure you aren't running `sudo minecraft-launcher`.  If you are, then yes, screenshots and other data are being saved to `/root/.minecraft`.  Run `minecraft-launcher` as your normal user.

If that's not the problem, then ...

- Confirm that you installed the official Minecraft Debian package [directly from Microsoft/Mojang](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative).
- Check the SHA256 hash on the file you originally downloaded compared to a fresh download.  If they are different, then there's a chance that your system is compromised.  However, it's also *possible* that the file was updated between your initial download and now.  You'll need to find some way to determine if that's the case.
- Ensure that `which minecraft-launcher` points to `/usr/bin/minecraft-launcher` and not some intermediate script.

Comment: I might even go as far as to suggest that that system needs to be re-installed.  Anyone using this minecraft server that knows how to exploit bugs in minecraft could have access to that system.

Comment: @Rinzwind Good catch - Thank you.

Comment: @Rinzwind On the bright side, it doesn't look like the user here is running a Minecraft server, but just the client.  But if the root problem is that the client itself is malicious, then the OP is still back in the same boat.